# How to match parentheses / brackets in pyparsing

Tags: python, grammar, pyparsing

I have a grammar token specified as:

```
list_value = Suppress(oneOf("[ (")) + Group(
    delimitedList(string_value | int_value))("list") + Suppress(oneOf("] )"))
```

However, this obviously allows `(foo, bar]`

How do I enforce that the lists opening and closing characters must match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make a list a choice between two rules: one for parentheses and one for square brackets. Thanks for bringing up pyparsing. I like it. My answer for your question is:

```
delim_value = Group(delimitedList(string_value | int_value))("list")
list_value = Or( (Suppress("[") + delim_value + Suppress("]"),
                  Suppress("(") + delim_value + Suppress(")")) )
```

Comment: This gives me an (seemingly unrelated) error when I try to parse a list surrounded with `(`'s

Comment: Works for me: `list_value.parseString("(1,2,3,'slkfj')").asList()` gives `[['1', '2', '3', "'slkfj'"]]`. Perhaps there is something wrong with your definition of string_value or int_value (I had to guess at them in my simulation). In fact, if string_value is something like `Word(printables)`, then this is going to cause problems in matching the enclosing ()'s; they will get slurped up into such a broadly-defined string_value. Pyparsing does not do backtracking like regexen do, but works strictly left-to-right. Add `.setDebug()` to your definition of string_value and see what you match with it.