# Capture literal brackets inside brackets in pyparsing

Tags: pyparsing

I'm trying to parse some functions arguments with PyParsing but am having trouble getting the right syntax.  Namely, given:

```
str = "(key=val())"
```

I would like the parser to return `['key', 'val()']`.

I've been trying to get this to work with the following code; the `.suppress()` calls are intentionally omitted for clarity.

```
ob = Literal("(")
cb = Literal(")")
key = Word(alphas)
value = Word(alpha + "()") 
parser = ob + key + "=" + value + cb
print parser.parseString(str)
```

but of course it's matching the final closing bracket as well and so I get a ParseException.

Is there an elegant solution to this?  For example, I looked at `nestedExpr` but in this case it's not strictly a nesting since I want the `val()` to be treated as a literal.  Similarly [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965009/how-to-match-parentheses-brackets-in-pyparsing) alludes to the problem but doesn't give a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of

```
value = Word(alpha + "()")
```

is overly liberal. Not only will it match trailing ()'s, but also any embedded ones, and regardless of matching opening and closing, values like:

```
SLDFJJ(sldkjf)
sdlkfj(sldkfj(lkskdjf)))(
```

and even just:

```
(((((())(()()()()
```

I suggest you define the syntax for an identifier, usually something like:

```
identifier = Word(alphas+'_', alphanums+'_')
```

and then compose value with:

```
value = Combine(identifier + '()')
```

Now the `value` expression won't erroneously accept any embedded `()`s, and will only parse the trailing `()` and nothing further.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for the clarification and the great software!