# Python Pyparsing: Capture comma-separated list inside parentheses ignoring inner parentheses

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, pyparsing

I have a question on how to properly parse the string like the following,

```
"(test.function, arr(3,12), "combine,into one")"
```

into the following list,

```
['test.function', 'arr(3,12)', '"combine,into one"']
```

Note: the 'list' items from the original string are not necessarily split by a comma and a space, it can also be two items split directly by a comma one after another, e.g. `test.function,arr(3,12)`.

Basically, I want to:

1. Parse the input string which is contained in parentheses, but not the inner parentheses. (Hence, `nestedExpr()` can't be used as-is)
2. The items inside are separeted by commas, but the items themselves may contain commas.

Moreover, I can only use `scanString()` and not `parseString()`.

I've done some search in SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420067/capture-literal-brackets-inside-brackets-in-pyparsing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785755/how-to-split-but-ignore-separators-in-quoted-strings-in-python), but I can't translate them to fit into my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should address your nesting and quoting issues:

```
sample = """(test.function, arr(3,12),"combine,into one")"""

from pyparsing import (Suppress, removeQuotes, quotedString, originalTextFor, 
    OneOrMore, Word, printables, nestedExpr, delimitedList)

# punctuation and basic elements
LPAR,RPAR = map(Suppress, "()")
quotedString.addParseAction(removeQuotes)

# what are the possible values inside the ()'s?
# - quoted string - anything is allowed inside quotes, match these first
# - any printable, not containing ',', '(', or ')', with optional nested ()'s
#   (use originalTextFor helper to extract the original text from the input
#   string)
value = (quotedString 
         | originalTextFor(OneOrMore(Word(printables, excludeChars="(),") 
                                     | nestedExpr())))

# define an overall expression, with surrounding ()'s
expr = LPAR + delimitedList(value) + RPAR

# test against the sample
print(expr.parseString(sample).asList())
```

prints:

```
['test.function', 'arr(3,12)', 'combine,into one']
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for sharing this solution. This one addresses my question. I'm aware of originalTextFor() and nestedExpr(), but never thought to implement both of them in such a way.